# How to redirect domain w/urls to single new domain and url

Tags: .htaccess

I would like to redirect a domain with all of its urls to a new single place

oldname.net/*wildcardpaths

to

newname.com/home.html

Ideally I can use a htaccess rule to properly scope the oldname.net urls and 301 them to the new homepage of the new domain name.

The use case here is we are retiring an old site and want to just point it and all of the inbound urls someone might have to just drop on the new site/domain homepage.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule in old domain's root .htaccess:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^ http://newname.com/home.html
```